# How to set the UITabBars items property when accessing through a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have build a UITabBarController programmatically and populated its `viewControllers` property.
When I run this the tabBar buttons are, of course, empty, I tried to access the `tabBar` property on the UITabBarController to set its `items` property to my text/images, which made the app crash.

Going through the documentation for the UITabBarController I read this under the tabBar property:

> The tab bar view associated
>   with this controller. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic,readonly) UITabBar
>   *tabBar Discussion You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar
>   object itself stored in this property.
>   If you attempt to do so, the tab bar
>   view throws an exception. To configure
>   the items for your tab bar interface,
>   you should instead assign one or more
>   custom view controllers to the
>   viewControllers property. The tab bar
>   collects the needed tab bar items from
>   the view controllers you specify.
>
> The tab bar view provided by this
>   property is only for situations where
>   you want to display an action sheet
>   using the showFromTabBar: method of
>   the UIActionSheet class.

This is what I want:

> The tab bar collects the needed tab
>   bar items from the view controllers
>   you specify.

It also makes perfect sense that you do not setup up the tabBar in one place and the content in another.

**But how do I define these items in my viewControllers which are all of type UINavigationController, with my custom ViewController as the rootController?**

**Is there some protocol besides the UITabBarControllerDelegate I need to implement?**

Hope someone could point me in the right direction, I did not see this one coming:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the tab bar items gets filled with the name of the view controller you are loading into it.

In your case you can do one thing,

```
[tabbarContrller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"rafsfsa" image:[UIImage imageName:@"some.png" tag:0];
```

Do reply if you get this in.

Comment: Hi Thanks...I do feel a bit stupid, I started to build the ViewControllers and when I did [self.navigationController setTitle:@"String"] the title turn up on the button. I then did [self.navigationController setTabBarItem:myItem] ... the methods were there, just as the documentation said, I was just focusing on the TabBarController.
Thanks again.